# Get actual year and month data from sql

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Please help me in this sql. How can i get the actual year, and the actual month data from the table? The foglalas_datum in the table is datetime. Thank you!

```
$check = mysqli_query($kapcs, "
SELECT 
    foglalas_id, 
    foglalas_nev,
    foglalas_tel,
    foglalas_email,
    foglalas_erkez_date,
    foglal_iroda_id, 
    foglal_type,  
    foglal_iroda_id 
FROM 
    foglalas  
WHERE 
    foglal_iroda_id='$iroda' 
    AND YEAR(foglalas_datum) = YEAR(NOW()) 
    AND MONTH(foglalas_datum) = MONTH(NOW())   
ORDER BY 
    foglalas_id DESC
") 
or die("Sql Error".mysqli_error($kapcs));
```

Comment: what is your problem? any error? how you want the output to be?

Comment: I have to rows in the table, where the foglalas_datum is 2014-05-14 19:17:23.  And the php echos out only 1 row. And i dont get any errors.

Answer (score 0):

```
$check = mysqli_query($kapcs, "
SELECT 
    foglalas_id, 
    foglalas_nev,
    foglalas_tel,
    foglalas_email,
    foglalas_erkez_date,
    foglal_iroda_id, 
    foglal_type,  
    foglal_iroda_id 
FROM 
    foglalas  
WHERE 
    foglal_iroda_id='$iroda' 
    AND YEAR(foglalas_datum) = YEAR(CURDATE()) 
    AND MONTH(foglalas_datum) = MONTH(CURDATE())   
ORDER BY 
    foglalas_id DESC
") 
or die("Sql Error".mysqli_error($kapcs));
```

please try CURDATE() instead of NOW()

Comment: With this code, it echos out all the rows, where the foglal_iroda_id is 1. Heres a link of the table.

http://kepfeltoltes.hu/140525/N_vtelen-2_www.kepfeltoltes.hu_.jpg